# Does not work SetActive for panel - Unity

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

The panel is not turned off via SetActive (false). I can not understand why, the object in the inspector is, then everything should work properly.

```cs
void Start() {
    HealthBar.SetActive (false);
}
public void Play() {
    HealthBar.SetActive (true);
}
```

[image]. How can you solve this problem?

Comment: Code is needed, how are we supposed to help without it?

Comment: @Galandil void Start()
{
HealthBar.SetActive (false);
}

public void Play() 
{
HealthBar.SetActive (true);
}
It's code

Comment: you have to edit your question and put the code there please

Comment: Since the panel is not getting Deactivated, Are you getting any error in playmode?

Comment: maybe you accidentally enabling it in update function  after you disabling the panel , check it out tooo...

Comment: Can you try and do a Debug.Log() and see if the Play() function dont get called?

Comment: Is your GameManager a Singleton? Also, is the current scene the first scene, or there's a previous scene?

Comment: @ZayedUpal GameManager is Singleton. I have only one scene and reloaded after click on the Play(). Maybe after reloading scene panel deactivated?

Comment: @Nikita does it work on the first time? When you hit play in the Unity Editor?